# (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

With the following code, I'm facing an issue.

ABC.h

```
namespace abcd
{
    class ABC
    {
    public:
        ABC() = delete;
        ABC(const std::string& filename);
        virtual ~ABC();
        ABC(const ABC&) = delete;
        ABC(ABC&&) = default;
    };
}
```

XYZ.h

```
using namespace abcd;

class XYZ
{
public:
    void func();
private:
    ABC obj;
    ABC maskfilename(std::string filename);
};
```

XYZ.cpp

```
XYZ::func()
{
    obj = maskfilename("abcd.txt"); //Error
}

abcd::ABC XYZ::maskfilename(string filename)
{
    abcd::ABC ret;
    // blah blah...
    return ret;
}
```

**Error:**

> "abcd::ABC::operator=(const abcd::ABC &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

I understand it is move constructor only class (`ABC`).

What is the right way to use this? I want to retain the return value from `maskfilename()` in the `XYZ` class, so it can be used in other functions of the `XYZ` class.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function cannot be referenced as it is a deleted function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827924/function-cannot-be-referenced-as-it-is-a-deleted-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you used a Microsoft compiler, you would get MSVC error [C2280](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2280?view=vs-2019):

> The compiler detected an attempt to reference a deleted function. This
> error can be caused by a call to a member function that has been
> **explicitly marked as = deleted** in the source code. This error can also
> be caused by a call to an **implicit special member function** of a struct
> or class that is **automatically declared and marked as deleted** by the
> compiler. For more information about when the compiler automatically
> generates default or deleted special member functions, see Special
> member functions.

In your case, apart from the conversion constructor, your class `ABC` only has a move constructor. Since you declared a move constructor, the compiler implicitly deleted the copy-assignment operator. You also explicitly deleted the copy constructor, i.e. you declared a copy constructor, just one that is deleted. This blocks the move assignment operator from being generated implicitly.

This line is trying to invoke your deleted  copy-assignment operator.

```
obj = maskfilename("abcd.txt"); //Error
```

You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/explicitly-defaulted-and-deleted-functions?view=msvc-170):

> - If any constructor is explicitly declared, then no default constructor is automatically generated.
> - If a virtual destructor is explicitly declared, then no default destructor is automatically generated.
> - If a move constructor or move-assignment operator is explicitly declared, then:
>
>   - No copy constructor is automatically generated.
>   - No copy-assignment operator is automatically generated.
> - If a copy constructor, copy-assignment operator, move constructor, move-assignment operator, or destructor is explicitly declared, then:
>
>   - No move constructor is automatically generated.
>   - No move-assignment operator is automatically generated.
>
> Additionally, the C++11 standard specifies the following additional
> rules:
>
> - If a copy constructor or destructor is explicitly declared, then automatic generation of the copy-assignment operator is deprecated.
> - If a copy-assignment operator or destructor is explicitly declared, then automatic generation of the copy constructor is deprecated.

Since you want your class to be a move-only class, just declare a move assignment operator. Then the same line will invoke your move assignment operator and move the value that `maskfilename` returns into `obj`.

Here's a reworked implementation of your class `ABC`:

```
class ABC
{
public:
    ABC() = delete;
    ABC(std::string filename) : mFilename(std::move(filename)) {}
    virtual ~ABC() = default;
    ABC(const ABC&) = delete;
    ABC& operator= (const ABC&) = delete;   //deleted copy-assignment operator
    ABC(ABC&&) = default;
    ABC& operator= (ABC&&) = default;   //added move assignment operator
    std::string GetFilename() const { return mFilename; }

private:
    std::string mFilename;
};
```

---

In your class `XYZ` you can't have a member variable `obj` of type `ABC` since the default constructor is deleted. If you need to use such an object in other methods of `XYZ` you could have a unique pointer to `ABC` instead. So I would change that like this:

XYZ.h:

```
#include "ABC.h"
#include <memory>

class XYZ
{
public:
    void func();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> obj;
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> maskfilename(std::string filename);
};
```

XYZ.cpp:

```
void XYZ::func()
{
    obj = std::move(maskfilename("abcd.txt"));
}

std::unique_ptr<ABC> XYZ::maskfilename(std::string filename)
{
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> ret = std::make_unique<ABC>(filename);
    // blah blah...
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: thanks for input. I tried that I still see issues like **Error** the default constructor of `"abcd::ABC"` cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function and **Error** function `"abcd::ABC::operator=(const abcd::ABC &)"` (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Comment: Thanks! But purpose of having  `ABC obj` object declared in `class XYZ`. So I need a mechanism to use `obj` in other methods of `class XYZ`. How can I achieve that functionality without calling `maskfilename` method multiple times.

Comment: @CodeDevil If you need to delay construction, consider `Optional<ABC>`, which can havef "no value" until it's constructed.